# Curious about the limits of LINQ and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm aware there are alternatives to what I'm asking, most of them easy and crystal clear. Consider this **a theoretical question**: How far from the usual sequential imperative paradigm can `LINQ` and lambda take me in this hypothetical case.

So, I have to read data about files. I obtain an `IEnumerable<string>` to the file names by doing `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path : string)`. I must call `MyMethod` on each file which isn't actually a folder.

First, I'll show the widely accepted alternatives (I would imagine these would be the top choices):

a fully imperative solution:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);
foreach(f in files)
{
    if(!Directory.Exists(f))
        MyMethod(f);
}
```

a two step solution:

```
var seq = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path) 
          where !Directory.Exists(file) 
          select file;

foreach(string str in seq)
{
    MyMethod(str);
}
```

Now using LINQ's extension methods explicitly to chain the the whole thing, which is the closest I can get from actually translating the line fully into a declarative paradigm:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
         .Where(f => !Directory.Exists(f))
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(f => MyMethod(f));
```

Now, I can't even begin to construct something that would be acceptable in the C# formal grammar, but I was imagining if I could do something similar in spirit to the line below

```
from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path) 
where !Directory.Exists(file) 
do MyMethod(file);
```

I know the "`do`" is specially out of place here, as it isn't even a lambda clause. My hope in including it was to make my intentions clearer.

Explaining what I meant: *for each element in the* `IEnumerable<string>` *returned by* `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path : string)`*, except those who don't satisfy the* `where` *clause, invoke* `MyMethod` *and pass* the `file` *element as an argument*.

Is there a pure LINQ "mini language" way of posing my intentions to the computer?

Comment: What does Directory.Exists do when you pass it a path that refers to a file?

Comment: You shouldn't want to. No LINQ clause accepts a statement (or an expression that returns `void`, same thing). Of course you could write a helper method (`int Do(Action a) { a(); return 0; }`, then `select Do(() => MyMethod(file))` that technically meets the patterns -- LINQ queries are not *prohibited* from having side effects, it's only a Terrible Idea. Use `foreach`, that's what it's there for. Queries *query for things*, they do not *act*.

Comment: Are you saying that "C# formal grammar" is LINQ? i.e. "Language Integrated Query"

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert.  When I was making my own first forays into using LINQ, the general advice I got was that it has it's place in terms of making some foreach type lookups and queries tidy and efficient.  But that big caveat that I got was  _prefer readable code over clever code_.

Comment: FYI, `EnumerateFiles` will only return files, while `EnumerateDirectories` will only return directories, so the `!Directory.Exists` check can be removed...

Comment: You can do it in a single line, but it's not all Linq: `foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)) MyMethod(file);`

Comment: Thank you. I was just curious about how far away from imperative programming I could go with LINQ, lambdas and the LINQ mini language.

Comment: An expression similar to how you're using `do` is under discussion for inclusion in C# 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you give `MyMethod` a return value. Otherwise there is nothing for `select` to return:

```
static bool MyMethod(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    return true;
}
```

Then you should be able to do the following, but there's still a problem:

```
var result = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path) 
    where !Directory.Exists(file) select MyMethod(file);
```

The method *does not actually execute until you do something with `result`*! To get around this, you can wrap the call in parenthesis and then call a method on the results that forces them all to execute, like `Count()`, or `ToList()`:

```
(from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path) select MyMethod(file)).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently as you have it, the best solution would be:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
  MyMethod(file);
}
```

However, if you want to continue down the chain, you can write MyMethod like this:

```
public static class MyExensions
{
  public static void MyMethod(this IEnumerable<string> files)
  {
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
      ... Do stuff with file ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call the above like so:

```
Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(path)
  .MyMethod();
```

or this:

```
(from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)).MyMethod();
```